# how to use bootstrap select box in add row

Tags: jquery

Here is my add row function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".kg").blur(function()
  {
    if($(".kg:last").val() > 0)
    {
      $("#one").clone(true).appendTo("#mainDiv")
      .find('input[type="text"]').val('').end()
      .find('select[option=""]').val('');
      var rowCount = $('#mainDiv tr').length;
      $(".srNo:last").val(rowCount);
    }
  });
});
```

Here i am using boostrop select with this function:

```
function add(thisObj)
{
  var row   = $(thisObj).parents('.itemRow');
   row.find.fn.select2.defaults.set("theme", "bootstrap");
   row.find(".hey").select2({
            width: null
   });
}
```

Here is my code with my add row function i want to apply select search in every row how it is possible i can not able to use in every row

Comment: can you pls provide the jsfiddle link ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wcm2o1tr/1/

Comment: @I'mBack https://jsfiddle.net/wcm2o1tr/1/

Comment: @PrashantBhatt did work?

Comment: take look my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wcm2o1tr/1/ @AlvaroJoao

Comment: @PrashantBhatt I already did and answered you on the chat.... please take a look on the answer as well. you are still not binding the function add to any event of the dom

Comment: @AlvaroJoao i want to apply select sarch in my add row function in ur example is about add row i want to implement select search in add row...

Comment: @PrashantBhatt I got that ... did you tried my approach ?

Comment: Yes i try already but not working @AlvaroJoao

Comment: nevermind... I'm not coding this for you

Comment: @AlvaroJoao as u like but you know how its work u must told me that where is my mistake..

Answer (score 0):

Just updated the answer, I guess you are trying to manipulate the event itself.

On click events the first object is an [`Event`](https://api.jquery.com/click/#click-eventData-handler) not the currentTarget.
to get just access them by using `.currentTarget`.

to get the [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) (all elements in same levels).

For filtering you **have** to use **[filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** function just like:

```
var elements_filters = $(element).siblings().filter('.class') //filter([selector])
```

you can use the [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function on the parent element to add other elements on the parent node as childs;

See the example below (click in the box):

```js
var add = function (obj){
  var filtered = $(obj.currentTarget).children().filter('.red')
 console.log(filtered); 
 $('div').html(filtered);
  
}

$("body").on("click", "tr", add);
```

```css
.red{
  background-color:red
}

table{
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="line">
    <td class="red">Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
response:
<div>
  </div>
```

Comment: just update the answer... if you want the actual code... you have to post the html snippet. @PrashantBhatt

Comment: function add(thisObj)
  {
    var elements_filters = $(thisObj).siblings().filter('.colorId')
    row.find.fn.select2.defaults.set("theme", "bootstrap");
    row.find(".colorId").select2({
            width: null
   });
 }

Comment: @PrashantBhatt please what is this `thisObj` ? please post the console.log() of this obj.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131610/discussion-between-prashant-bhatt-and-alvaro-joao).